# Properties with generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Is it possible to have properties with generic type?

What I am trying to do:

Have a base class called `Value` with the following structure:

```
class Value {
  var genericProperty: T

  init<T>(type: T) {
      switch type.self {
      case is Int.Type:
        genericProperty is Int
      case is [Int.Type]:
        genericProperty is [Int]
      default:
        genericProperty is Any
      }
  }
}
```

Then have a bunch of subclasses that define what the type of `genericProperty` should be.

Something like this:

```
class IntValue: Value {
  override init<T>(type: T) {
      super.init(type: Int.self)
  }
}

class IntArrayValue: Value {
  override init<T>(type: T) {
      super.init(type: [Int.self])
  }
}
```

Is this somehow possible with `associatedType` or any of the sorts?

For clarification (possibly this design is bad). I would like to do something along this line:

```
func handle(values: [Value]) {
  values.forEach {
    switch $0 {
      case is IntValue.Type:
        // Here I will now know that `genericProperty` will have type `Int` 
        // and can assign to a property with `Int` type

        property: Int = $0.genericProperty
      case is IntArrayValue.Type:
        // Here I know it will be an array
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You had to make whole class generic.

Comment: Yeah, I usually have Swiftlint throwing errors at my head, but I typed this in SO editor itself. I was happy that I got readable code.

Comment: As you've suspected, this design is probably wrong. It looks like you're trying to reinvent a PAT (protocol with associated type) with classes. Typically if you're calling `case is` a lot, you've broken encapsulation. The fact that you accept `Any` as one of the options also suggests major problems in the design that you should reconsider. The whole point of generics is to avoid `Any`, not to move it down one layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but... you can create a generic base class and add subclasses which specify the concrete type:

```
class Value<T> {
  var value: T
  init(_ value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}
```

Now some subclasses with specific value type:

```
class IntValue: Value<Int> {}
class StringValue: Value<String> {}
```

And here's how to use them:

```
let intValue = IntValue(42)
intValue.value // 42

let stringValue = StringValue("Hi")
stringValue.value // "Hi"
```

Comment: I just came up with the same solution. Not sure why I tried to make it so complicated when the solution itself was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is no.

In your example, `genericProperty` would have a different type in the subclass to the superclass and that would break the type system. If you could do it, you could then legitmiately try something like this:

```
var array: [Value] = []
array.append(IntValue())
array.append(FloatValue())

for v in array
{
    let foo = v.genericProperty
}
```

What should the compiler infer for the type of `foo`?

Comment: Yep, this doesn't make any sense. @dr_barto's solution is the one I want, although I was not able to express it.