# Prevent force downcasting

Tags: swift, casting

This question is mainly a follow-up question of [Properties with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830357/properties-with-generic-type)

As my English skills are lacking to describe the problem in short, I will have to layout the problem and describe my current (flawed) implementation. The basic gist of the problem is that I want to have a central system 
where other systems can register to and receive a bunch of so called `Value`s.

Let's say `System A` and `System B` register at a `Central System Manager (CSM)`.

The `CSM` saves a reference to those two systems and dispatches a number of `Value`s,
if there are new ones. The systems have a receive handler where they can pick out the values that they are interested in (but they will always receive all values – as a dictionary).

So my setup is the following:

```
// The ValueIDs are a unique way to identify the different value types
enum ValueIDs: Int {
    case DistanceValueId = 0
    case SpeedValueId = 1
}

// A very generic value class
class Value: Hashable {
    var id: Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hashValue
    }

    var value: Any

    static func ==(lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    init(id: Int = 0, value: Any) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
}

// These are concrete value implementations
class DistanceValue: Value {
    override init(id: Int = 0, value: Any) {
        super.init(id: ValueIDs.DistanceValueId.rawValue, value: value)
    }
}

class DescriptionValue: Value {
    override init(id: Int = 0, value: Any) {
        super.init(id: ValueIDs.SpeedValueId.rawValue, value: value)
    }
}

// The `Value`s dictionary is being initialized and appended with concrete implementations
// of `Value`
var values: [Int: Any] = [:]

let intV = DistanceValue(value: 123)
let stringV = DescriptionValue(value: "Hello")

func addValue(_ value: Value) {
    values[value.id] = value.value
}

addValue(intV)
addValue(stringV)

// The is the point where the systems, i.e. `System A` and `System B`
// would receive the `values` dictionary and would pick out the values that
// they are interested in.
// `System A`, for example, would only be interested in `DistanceValue`
let testInt: Int = values[ValueIDs.DistanceValueId.rawValue] as! Int

// `System B` would only be interested in the `SpeedValue`
let testString: String = values[ValueIDs.SpeedValueId.rawValue] as! String
```

The current implementation works, but I would like to prevent the downcast at the `System` level. Is there a nicer way/design to achieve what I'm trying or is there a way to move the downcast further up, so the `System`s don't need to do it?

Comment: Just a note that classes might not be needed, your design seems to be better fit for structs usage.

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit from an example of how this is used and an example of code that you are trying to "fix". (FYI - your English is better than most posters).

Comment: "The ValueIDs are a unique way to identify the different value types" Any time you do that, you're breaking encapsulation, as you were rightly told in the responses to your earlier question. The whole _point_ of inheritance is so that you don't do that sort of thing. Could be class and subclasses, could be protocol and struct adopters, whatever. But a thing should _be_ the type of thing it is, not a blank thing with an artificial type label.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get better results by using an enum with associated values:

```
enum Value {
    case distance(Int)
    case speed(Int)
}

extension Value: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.distance(value1), .distance(value2)),
             let (.speed(value1), .speed(value2)):
            return value1 == value2
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

extension Value: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
            case let .distance(value),
                 let .speed(value):
            return value.hashValue
        }
    }
}
```

, and store the enum values in an array instead of a dictionary.

Comment: As I've mentioned before, in Swift 4.1 the implementation of `==` and `hashValue` becomes unnecessary; the compiler will synthesize them for you when you adopt Hashable.